# How to enable hotspot in React Native on onPress Event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.arrowImgBlock} onPress={__need to enable hotspot__}>
     <Image
       source={require('./src/images/arrow.png')}
       style={styles.arrowImg}
     />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

i am bit worried on how can we enable hotspot in react native onPress event?please anyone help me out on this?

Comment: please use HotpotPackage to see whether it suits your needs --- 

import reactnative.hotspot.HotspotPackage;

Comment: @KenLee i found couple of libraries like (react-native-wifi-hotspot) but these library not worked for me..

Comment: @RajeshMaruti Please, describe what do you want to do with your element. Library that you mentioned is about wifi communication and have nothing to deal with active page elements. So you should clarify your problem..